# char* pointer from string in C#

Tags: c#, pointers, char

Is it possible to get a `char*` for a `string` variable in C#?

I need to convert a path string to a `char*` for using some native win32 function ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can pass a `StringBuilder` as a `char*`.

Have a look at http://pinvoke.net to see if the signature for the function is not already there.

Comment: I am awarding this answer since you basically answered my question but it seems that, at least for what I was doing all that was needed was fixed(char* s = string){...}

Comment: I tried this with SecureString(char*, int length) and neither SecureString(sb, sb.Length) or SecureString((char*)sb, sb.Length) works. Says cannot convert System.Text.StringBuilder to char*.

Comment: I tried this, but I got "cannot convert from 'System.Text.StringBuilder' to 'char*"

Answer (score 63):

Well you could certainly do this:

```
string str = "my string";

unsafe 
{
    fixed (char* p = str)
    {               
        // do some work
    }
}
```

where there is an operator (char*) bound to the string object.
However, the output format may not be compatible with the underlying C or other format... this is however quite a good solution to parse the string.
Hope it's helpful for anybody who reads this post.

Comment: This gives a pointer to `System.Char` elements, which corresponds to Win32's `WCHAR*`, but the question asks for `char *`.

Comment: @TomBlodget `char` is a type alias for `System.Char`.

Comment: @DrewNoakes True. I was reading `char` in the question as meaning a native char. The intent is not so clear to me now.

Comment: This caused an access violation for me when p is passed to a native function.

Answer (score 9):

No unsafe context is required for the following piece of code (and yeah it shows the internal bolts and bits about the implementation of `string`'s `GetHashCode` method shows it's difference with one in Java because in C# the value of hashcode isn't cached and generally it shows that C# strings are not ultimately immutable like you might have been taught, can't deal with Fon Neiman):

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Guess
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string str = "ABC";

            Console.WriteLine(str);
            Console.WriteLine(str.GetHashCode());

            var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(str, GCHandleType.Pinned);

            try
            {
                Marshal.WriteInt16(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), 4, 'Z');

                Console.WriteLine(str);
                Console.WriteLine(str.GetHashCode());
            }
            finally
            {
                handle.Free();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @zwcloud **Its totally wrong thing to state, the answer is correct and the most efficient and least opinionated (in relation to unsafe context)**. The answer does exactly what it was asked to do. Pinning string's pointer through `GCHandle.alloc` won't make any memory leaks unless you will impose improper use of pointers later in an underlying context. The whole pointer / memory concept in C# is considered low-level / advanced topic and if you go with pointers it means that you understand the whole concept and basically know what you are doing.

Comment: In relation to referenced question and answer, the point is totally valid but has nothing to do to above question, it was not mentioned that anyone will store pointer. If you were to store for later use a string created in C# than obviously you would need to have it copied in C because it would involve the allocation of that string in C which would allow C to have it later deallocated. So it generally means that you just can't pin your pointer for life neither it is good to marshal (create) a copy of your string in C# and have it stored in C because C will not be able to deallocate it later.

Answer (score 5):

That depends on what you want to do. When you call a Win32 function via PInvoke, you should be able to just pass the String variable; the framework marshals everything for you. If you need something more complicated, have a look at [Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtohglobalansi.aspx) and other methods of the `Marshal` class.

Answer (score 4):

To combine 2 anwers already given, it depends on the direction you need for your parameter.

If the function just needs an input string, ie `const char *`, you can use an argument of type `System.String` (or plain `string`).

If the function fills a string, ie  `char * buffer, int bufferSize`, you can pass a `System.Text.StringBuilder` .

In both cases the (auto-)Marshaling will do the necessary conversions for you.

Comment: Thanks already for the insights but I have some additional remarks in the comments of a post below...

Comment: Thank you for explaining the difference between a function that just takes a string, and one that builds a string. Everyone just kept touting `StringBuilder` but that didn't seem right if the function isn't going to modify the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can get byte[] array from string using Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes.
This is probably convertible to char* using fixed statement in C#. (This pins the allocated memory, not allowing gc to move it - then you can make a pointer to it).

So my answer is yes only if you manage to convert byte* to char*.
(in C/C++ this wouldn't be a problem, but I'm not that sure about C#)

PS> I'll post some code later if I find a bookmark to an article on this. I know I have it somewhere..

Comment: You should also consider Encoding.UTF8 as that will preserve all unicode characters.

Comment: Or rather, it's better to use Encoding.Unicode (and PWSTR on the C end) if passing to a native Win32 function...

Comment: You have to check first if those aren't multibyte(and I think that they in fact are), because this complicates it a "little bit"..

Comment: Funny that you should mention "fixed". Studying an assembly (using reflector) I found online an that relies on interaction with Win32 entities I saw a method that takes a string argument. The first thing that happens to the string is fixed( char* path = (char*)strargument){...}. The Char* eventually gets assigned to a win32 struct (WINTRUST_FILE_INFO.LPCWSTR parameter). Trying this for myself for educational purposes does not work (compiler says "cannot convert string to char*") I do not understand why is this compiler generated, did the orig. code assign the string directly to the struct?

Comment: Did some more research... it appears that it is valid in C# to just do something like: string test = "test"; fixed (char* p = test){..}. The thing that threw me of is that the compiler uglies this up by generating: private static unsafe void Main()
    {
        string test = "test";
        fixed (char* CS$519$0000 = ((char*) test))
        {
            char* p = CS$519$0000;
        }
    }
Which made me thing I would need to be able to find ways to convert string to char* Who'd have thought it would be as simple as char* = string;

Comment: The thing that set me on the right track is: 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: -1: You don't need to convert to byte[]. See Guillau pelletier's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Like some other posts pointed out, `fixed (char* p = str)` is not really compatible with native format and `StringBuilder` does not really work either. This is what worked for me:

```
fixed (byte* p = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str))
{
    native_call((char*)p);
}
```

Comment: That p not have `\0` in the end. Then native maybe access violation or read length greater than byte[].Length