# Invoke method for dll in WindowsForms

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, invoke

I have a dll which contains this function:

```
int __stdcall PrnText(char *printtext);
```

In Windows Forms i have this code to invoke the dll:

```
[DllImport("Printing.dll", EntryPoint = "PrnText", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern int PrnText(char *printtext);
```

When i call the function in C# code i get an error like this : " cannot cast string to char*

```
PrnText("Hello World");
```

What parameter should i give to PrnText() to make it work?

Later edit:

```
  Parameter: printtext
  pointer to string containing text to be printed
```

Comment: Looks like it is related to an [answered question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658269/char-pointer-from-string-in-c-sharp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CLR knows how to convert a `string` to an unmanaged `char*` at runtime. You should use a signature which accepts a `string`, as such:

```
public static extern int PrnText(string printtext);
```

Note that this will work only if the parameter is input only.

Comment: Do you mean input by the user ? Like a textbox or something?

Comment: It will only work if the code you're calling does not need to edit the string. In that were the case, you'd need to pass a `StringBuilder`, since strings are immutable.

Comment: @Emil No, I mean input only as in the dll function is not changing the `char*` in any way.

Comment: @EmilDumbazu: no, it means you can only pass a string as an input parameter to your native code - it won't be able to modify it. If your native function needs to mutate a string, pass a `StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: could you give me an example with StringBuilder ?

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179270/pass-c-sharp-string-to-c-and-pass-c-result-string-char-whatever-to-c-s

Comment: Or in other words, the C declaration is wrong.  It should have declared the argument as `const char*`.  This is a common oversight.