# Marshall c# string to c++

Tags: c#, marshalling

I would want to know how to marshall a C# string to a native C++ char*. I was trying it but nothing seems to work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [char* pointer from string in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658269/char-pointer-from-string-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a C++ char is actually a byte so you need to pass it as a byte[] using something like

```
string str; // Contains string to pass to C++ DLL
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
MyFun(bytes); // Call the C++ function with the string
```

See also [Pass C# string to C++ and pass C++ result (string, char*.. whatever) to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179270/pass-c-sharp-string-to-c-and-pass-c-result-string-char-whatever-to-c-s) for a different perspective.

Comment: You should not normally need to do that - you should normally just be able to declare the function as taking a System.String parameter.